# How do I install multiple java command-line programs?

Tags: bash, executable, java

I have a bunch of java command-line programs I've written and would like to install for all users.

Building with NetBeans, I get a `/dist` directory which contains `myprog1.jar` and a `/libs` directory with all the necessary libraries.  The usual method to run is to go there and `java -jar my.jar -options`.

So what I'd like to do is just type `myprog1 -options` from anywhere and have it run.

The method I have thought of is:

1. Create `/opt/myjava/myprog1` which contains `myprog1.jar` and its
   `/libs`.
2. Create a bash script `myprog1` in `/usr/local/bin` which simply redirects all of the command line args to `java -jar /opt/myjava/myprog1/myprog1.jar`

I'm not too keen on bash scripting... if this is a reasonable method, what would that script look like, given that each program has a variable number and order of arguments?  Does the script have to also worry about standard Unix bits such as output redirect `>` and pipes `|`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single wrapper script that executes a jar named after the way it's called, and make one symbolic link for each jar. Here's the jar-wrapper script (warning, typed directly into the browser):

```
#!/bin/sh
name=$(basename "$0")
jar=
for dir in /opt/myjava/*; do
  if [ -e "$dir/$name.jar" ]; then jar=$dir/$name.jar; break; fi
done
if [ -z "$jar" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$name.jar not found"
  exit 126
fi
exec /your/favorite/java -jar "$jar" "$@"
```

Then create as many symbolic links to the wrapper script as you like, and put them in your `$PATH` if you want:

```
ln -s wrapper-script myprog1
ln -s wrapper-script myprog2
```

---

If you are running Linux, and you are the system administrator, then you can select a Java interpreter to make jars directly executable, thanks to the [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) mechanism.

For example, on my system:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/jar
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/jre/lib/jexec
flags: 
offset 0
magic 504b0304
```

This system is documented in [`Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt) in the Linux kernel documentation. To create an entry like the one above, run the command

```
jexec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/jre/lib/jexec
echo >/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register ":jar:M:0:504b0304::$jexec:"
```

Your distribution may have a mechanism in place for binfmt registration at boot time. On Debian and derivatives, this is [`update-binfmts`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-binfmts&sektion=8), and the JVM packages already register `jexec`.

If you need to pass options, register a wrapper script that adds the options instead of `jexec` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the script, it worked unmodified.  I put the symbolic links in `/etc/rc.local`, creating links in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 3):

Bash and the Java executable know how to handle the redirection stuff. You want to use `exec` in order to replace the script interpreter running the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec java -jar ....jar "$@"
```