# Getting Java programs start without calling with Java

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, executable

It would be handy to be able to start Java programs by just calling the class file from the terminal (and have it running it the terminal when double-clicked in GUI, but this is less important). I so far only help myself with the following ad hoc fix:

```
alias cs='java charstat.Charstat'
```

Linux recognises the files as Java:

```
 charstat/Charstat.class: compiled Java class data, version 52.0 (Java 1.8)
```

So is there a way to have the call hard-wired? Ubuntu 16.04 here, but general answers welcome.

---

End of the question, troubleshooting section starts.

---

UPDATE

So far the most promising line of action is the one proposed by Gilles. So I ran:

`echo ":java-class:M:0:cafebabe::/usr/bin/java:" | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`

Now,

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~/Desktop$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/java-class
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/java
flags: 
offset 0
magic 6361666562616265
```

But,

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~/Desktop$ ./Void.class 
bash: ./Void.class: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

This was done on Ubuntu 14.04. It has:

```
binfmt-support/trusty,now 2.1.4-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Support for extra binary formats
```

which I think was not installed automatically on 16.04 if that matters.

Yesterday already, following Mark Plotnick's comment, I wrestled with [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java), to no avail. It introduced a wrapper at `/usr/local/bin/javawrapper`, which Gilles' solution doesn't contain. That's for Arch Linux though.

UPDATE 2 (Ubuntu 16.06)

On 16.06:

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~/Desktop/io$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/Java 
enabled
interpreter /usr/local/bin/javawrapper
flags: 
offset 0
magic cafebabe
```

And,

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~/Desktop/io$ ./Nain.class 
bash: ./Nain.class: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE 3

After `echo ":java-class:M:0:\xca\xfe\xba\xbe::/usr/bin/java:" | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register` :

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~/Desktop/io$ java Main 
Please input the file location and name.
^Ctomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~/Desktop/io$ ./Main.class 
Error: Could not find or load main class ..Main.class
```

For the record:

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc$ cat java-class 
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/java
flags: 
offset 0
magic cafebabe
```

Comment: Does this help? [binfmt_misc for java](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java)

Comment: Yes, that's gonna be it. Thanks. Only getting it up and running is not that easy, alas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Linux

Ubuntu already does this for a jar. With the [openjdk-8-jre package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openjdk-8-jre-headless) (and earlier versions), executing a jar invokes `jexec` on it. This isn't done for a class, maybe because it's rare for a class to be a standalone executable rather than a library (then again, that's also the case for jars).

You can configure the same underlying mechanism to handle classes. That mechanism is the Linux [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) feature, which allows the kernel to execute arbitrary files via a helper program.

Because Java's command line is really weird, you need to go through a wrapper to convert the file name into something that the `java` command is capable of executing. Save this script as `/usr/local/bin/javarun` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  */*) dir="${1%/*}"; base="${1##*/}";;
  *) dir="."; base="$1";;
esac
shift
case "$base" in
  [!-]*.class) base="${base%.*}";;
  *) echo >&2 "Usage: $0 FILENAME.class [ARGS...]"; exit 127;;
esac
case "$CLASSPATH" in
  "") exec java -cp "$dir" "$base" "$@";;
  *) exec java -cp "$dir:$CLASSPATH" "$base" "$@";;
esac
```

The following command should to the trick for classes. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21651 and the [kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt)  for explanations.

```
echo ":java-class:M:0:\xca\xfe\xba\xbe::/usr/local/bin/javarun:" | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

Run this once to enable it. To remove a setting, run `sudo rm /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/java-class`. Once you're happy with the setting, add the following command to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo >/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register ":java-class:M:0:\xca\xfe\xba\xbe::/usr/local/bin/javarun:"
```

### Zsh

If you use [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) as your shell, you can make it execute files based on their extension, by defining a [suffix alias](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-alias).

```
alias -s class=javarun
```

You need the same `javarun` script as above. Of course this only works in zsh, not in bash, file managers, scripts (except zsh scripts where this command has run), ...

Comment: @tomas Sorry, I forgot to escape the hex sequences in the magic string. See my edit.

Comment: I appended the contents of `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/java-class` to the last update.

Comment: @tomas Ugh, java. The binfmt_misc part was working, but you can't execute Java class just by running `java /path/to/file.class`, no. You need a wrapper script. See my edit.

Comment: Never mind. I didn't set o+x on `javarun`. Thanks.

Comment: In your script, where from will Bash know the variable `$CLASSPATH`? Is binfmt setting it?

Comment: @tomas `CLASSPATH` comes from your environment. I wrote the script to cope with both cases: `CLASSPATH` set or `CLASSPATH` unset. The directory containing the class file is prepended to the classpath, which could change the order of resolution of classes used by the main class, I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: You may be interested in [the sequel to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299906/calling-java-programs-without-the-class-suffix). Tx.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a mailcap item for ".class", and persuade your browser (or desktop launcher) to use this.

However, that would be just changing *which* program you ran to start execution (no real savings).  The same is true of desktop launchers.

Further reading:

- [mime/mailcap cli launcher?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mime-mailcap-cli-launcher-374659/)
- [Desktop Entry Standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-0.9.3.html)
- [Linux equivalent of the Mac OS X “open” command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264395/linux-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command)

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. I'm more interested in a solution for the command line though. I just corrected my question, sorry.

Comment: The first link points to a command-line "run-mailcap" which might be useful.

Comment: As you noticed, no real savings. But it gives some insight into the problem.